# How to translate modifier + key(control + space) into another modifier(shift)?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I've tried `xmodmap`, `xbindkeys + xdotool` with no luck.

Here's an example solution that I've tried with xmodmap.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 65 control = space Shift_L"
```

Comment: Another option might be [at home modifier](https://gitlab.com/at-home-modifier/at-home-modifier-evdev/wikis/home) or [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape), which can make keys dual-functional. When you press space normally, it sends a space. When you hold it and press another key, it sends a shift.

Comment: I've tried xcape translating space to shift, it doesn't work well.

Comment: This is illegal xmodmap syntax, and xmodmap doesn't support what you want. Read up on [xkb](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058), make your own custom keyboard layout with a "compatibility map" (misleading name) that does what you want.

Comment: I know that [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices/24930#24930) answer is old; however, it does show the syntax above.